# NHibernate queryover with many-to-many

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

The situation is following:
1. Product belongs to many Categories,
2. Category has many Products.

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

How to have all products, where each of them belongs to category with id = 2 and 3 and 4.  How to do with queryover?
At the moment I use dynamically created hql:

```
select p from Product p where 
exists (select c.id from p.Categories c where c.Id = 2) 
and exists (select c.id from p.Categories c where c.Id = 3)
and exists (select c.id from p.Categories c where c.Id = 4)
```

And the mapping is:

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Categories)
            .Table("product_category")
            .ParentKeyColumn("product_id")
            .ChildKeyColumn("category_id");
    }
}

public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
            .Table("product_category")
            .ParentKeyColumn("category_id")
            .ChildKeyColumn("product_id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it's help:

```
Category categoryAlias = null;
session.QueryOver<Product>()
  .JoinAlias(product => product.Categories, () => categoryAlias)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(() => categoryAlias.Id).IsIn(new [] { 2, 3, 4 })
  .List();
```